# Check if string length entered is equal to three

Tags: java, string, char

I need to create a code that checks if the input from the user is equal to a double literal length 3.  my if statement is where i am having trouble. Thanks

```
Scanner stdIn= new Scanner(System.in);
String one;
String two;
String three;

System.out.println("Enter a three character double literal ");
one = stdIn.nextLine();

if (!one.length().equals() "3")
{
  System.out.println(one + " is not a valid three character double literal");
}
```

Comment: Question edited: code formatted. [tag:eclipse] tag removed. Next time you will want to tell us exactly what "trouble" you might be having.

Answer (score 8):

[Comparison](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
if (one.length() != 3)
```

instead of

```
if (!one.length().equals() "3")
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (one.length() != 3)`

`if (!(one.length().equals(3))`

Both these ways work.

For more details please refer this.

https://www.leepoint.net/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(one.length().equals(3)) {
    System.out.println(one + " is not a valid three character double literal");
}
```

You have to place the `3` as an argument to the `equals` function ([it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) takes an argument).

More common is to use `==` when comparing numbers though.

```
if (!(one.length() == 3) {
    System.out.println(one + " is not a valid three character double literal");
}
```

or more concise:

```
if (one.length() != 3) {
    System.out.println(one + " is not a valid three character double literal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use .equals() as the length method returns an int.

```
if ( one.length() != 3 ) { do something; }
```